# How to try not to republish after clicking "Finish Editing" Button on experience manager

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, configuration

I try **not** to republish after clicking "Finish Editing" Button on experience manager.

But I click "Finish Editing" Button on experience manager, the following message appear and the page is re-published.

> The content of this page was successfully republished.
>
> After reloading the page, all visitors will see the latest changes
>   that were approved for publishing.

I want to publish the page by clicking "Publish" Button.

So tell me how **not** to republish after clicking "Finish Editing" Button on experience manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page is published in the Staging/Preview site only. Live should not be affected, for that you explicitly need to publish. This is by design.  If you're using the XPM then users would expect to see the latest content for inline editing.